# Mostrar modal com TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, script, modal

Olá, estou fazendo um código em que vou precisar abrir um modal Bootstrap no TypeScript, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Me ajudem aí por favor.

Vou deixar um exemplo pra vcs já pegarem aqui.

```js
function Abrir(){
    document.getElementById("myModal").modal('show');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>This is a small modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-       dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" onclick="Abrir()">Clique para abrir o modal</button>
```

EU NÃO ESTOU USANDO ANGULAR, MEU TRABALHO É EM .NET

**OBS:** Eu preciso fazer abrir com o TypeScript, não posso usar da seguinte maneira:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir modal</button>
```

pois nao será aberto ao clicar em um botão, no meu projeto.

Comment: Até onde eu sei, `modal()` não é um método da classe `Element`. Será que você não deveria estar chamando isso através de um objeto gerado pelo jQuery? Com `$("#myModal").modal('show')`

Comment: @user140828, eu nao estou usando jQuery, teria que ser com TypeScript mesmo

Comment: Voce esta com um projeto  a parte que esta escrito em TypeScript, que compila seu fonte end em javascript?